# Jmeter - How to match specific string - regex

Tags: jmeter

I am very new to regex in the jmeter.
Using a regular extractor & Having this text:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
server: nginx/1.21.0
date: Thu, 21 Apr 2022 10:20:25 GMT
content-type: application/json
transfer-encoding: chunked
x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.16
expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, private, post-check=0, pre-check=0
x-content-type-options: nosniff
content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'self';
set-cookie: SSESS8b04132f4690dc8ceb7837d5134a5519=7ERzAds0LT6MOicEKW62op7TGL2OtbB2EVdEyjJ0an8; path=/; domain=m-test.net; secure; HttpOnly
set-cookie: su=1; expires=Sun, 18-Apr-2032 10:20:25 GMT; Max-Age=315360000; path=/; domain=m-test.net;
```

What is the easiest way to fetch: **7ERzAds0LT6MOicEKW62op7TGL2OtbB2EVdEyjJ0an8** (the value of the first cookie) which is variable and always has different value

Note: the key: **SSESS8b04132f4690dc8ceb7837d5134a5519** is variable and always has different value.

Comment: maybe not the best but good enough in my opinion: `set-cookie:\s.*?SSESS.+?=(?<value_to_fetch>.+?);`

Comment: Thanks for the efforts: but SSESS8b04132f4690dc8ceb7837d5134a5519 is variable. Next run will has different value :)

Comment: I gave for granted that first part as being a constant for session .. sorry, you clearly stated in your question that detail. Well in that case the only criteria to filter that variable inside the set-cookie header without knowing in advance its name pattern and nor of its value, it's guessing on their length. It's not safe at all but according to the conditions you showed above, this could suffice?  `set-cookie:\s.*?.[a-zA-Z0-9]{10,}?=(?<value_to_fetch>.+?);` ... it's fetching the variable where the name is like or longer than 10 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
set-cookie:\s*.*=(.+?);\s*path=/
```

[image]

where:

- `\s*` - any number of optional whitespaces
- `()` - grouping
- `.` - any character
- `+` - repetition
- `?` - non greedy match on the filter

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T. Would it be too much if I aks you the regex for the key variable as well? (SSESS8b04132f4690dc8ceb7837d5134a5519 )? Or you prefer another thread Thanks

Comment: Better to start another cause it's not connected to the original question. And provide as many possible dynamic values as possible, this way the regex will be more accurate. In its current state you can use just `(\w+)`

Comment: thanks, that was helpful as well. this was the macher that helped me:   set-cookie: (\w+)